# What is the proper site in which to ask questions about general management?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Related, but not a duplicate of: [Project Management, Software Design and Human Factors should be within the Scope of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6643/project-management-software-design-and-human-factors-should-be-within-the-scope)

I'm interested in discussing topics on general management, that aren't necessarily related to programming. I think there are many users on SO that are interested in this as well. Here's a question that caught my attention just now:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532509/how-to-ask-questions-to-an-obstructionist

The question is *clearly* not programming related at all (even though a programming example was used in that context), so it does not belong on SO. But even so, I still think it's an interesting question that should be asked. (Note: I did not vote to close.)

Does there exist a forum in which to ask these types of questions? ManagementOverflow? :)

I realize there is a grey area here, where management topics *specifically related to software development and programming* should be asked and archived on SO -- that I agree with. However, as the example I cited above, some questions clearly belong elsewhere.

Comment: I've very interested in economic centered questions, but that doesn't mean that they're programming related necessarily. If it's programming related, you're fine. If it isn't, you risk it being closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of [StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) website.

There are a few under Business and Startups that might be suitable for such a question.

Comment: I read the list before posting. There isn't anything for this kind of thing. Project management is too narrow, and "general business" is too general IMO.

Comment: "Topics on general management" doesn't fit in "general business"? Huh?

Comment: I never said it didn't. What I said was that "general business" is too unfocused for the topics I want to discuss. The site in question is WhenBusiness.com -- if you look there, people are discussing everything from property leases to advertising to cell phone plans (and I only read the titles from the 10 most recent posts!).

Comment: So what, though? StackOverflow discusses assembly, PHP, CSS, HTML, Java, etc. all on one site, and it works just fine. Why can't the same be true for a business site?

Comment: I took the time this weekend to check out some of these sites. The communities on them so far are quite small (3 pages of users or less).

Comment: @Jon Seigel   Why not ask your question in those communities? Even if the communities are small you usually get great answers within 24 hours (I am one of the fellows behind http://AskAboutProjects.com a SE site on project management)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine Startups.com is more the place for this sort of thing.

Comment: I dunno. My company's been around for 30 years and we still have management issues....